# Dropdownlist loses selection after auto refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

i have a dropdownlist that once i choose a selection then the correct info displays in my gridview... Now with my app, the app must refresh after 10 seconds due to the nature of my app... But after the first refresh my selection clears and goes back to the default selection..

I understand what is happening i just cant figure out how to change this.. I have enabled viewstate and autopostback to my dropdownlist but after each postback it is still not getting my last selection... I understand after the postback that everything is saved, but how can i save my selection in view state.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (ddl.Items.Count == 0)
                    {
                        BindDropDownList();
                    }


                    BizManager mgr = new BizManager();
                    mgr.CalcShiftPeriod();

                    _ShiftStart = mgr.Shiftstart;
                    _ShiftEnd = mgr.Shiftend;


                    //RefreshLabeldata(214, DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-06-06," DateTime.TryParseExact("2016 - 06 - 06"));

                    RefreshData(ProductId,
                        _ShiftStart,
                        _ShiftEnd);
                }
            }



public void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //this fires after a DDL selection
        {

            ddl.EnableViewState = true;
            RefreshData(ProductId, _ShiftStart, _ShiftEnd);

        }
```

I have a meta refresh to refresh the page

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" > <%--refreshes after 10 seconds --%>
```

Comment: If its a complete refresh your selection wont be saved. if its just postback then it should save

Comment: how do i get it to keep its state after a meta refresh? (but i want the data to update still every 10 seconds)

Comment: i think for you using jquery and ajax is the better option, than what you are trying to do from posting back every 10 s

Comment: I just need some way of keeping the data in the page after a refresh

Comment: you can use,session to store your selected value, but its not a very good or efficient way. if you open 2 tabs, everything will get messed up.

Comment: or store the selecting in a hiddenfiled then you can access the value after refresh, using Page.PreviousPage and findcontrol

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier : thats not correct approaches to use even if it achieves the target its not recommended

Comment: @HanyHabib this is a selected index. If the user wants to tamper with it he doesnt need to meddle with the hidden field. since the data is not sensitive, hidden field is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i just wanted to give you a heads up. I managed to find a solution... Adding javascript in the head of the markup.. As below.

```
<script>
       window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 5000); //refresh the page (without losing state)
   </script>
```